# Word clustering in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, cpu-word

How to cluster only words in a given set of Data: i have been going through few algorithms online like k-Means algotihm,but it seems they are related to document clustering instead of word clustering.Can anyone suggest me some way to only cluster words in a given set of data???.
please am new to python.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: (1) Different tasks require different type of clusters. Can you specify the task and which words you believe belong to the same clusters? 
(2) Are you focusing on English only?

Comment: Can i cluster all the words based on polarity of each word from a given dataset.for eg- words like kill,burn etc have negative polarity so all these words should be under one cluster.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the fact that my last answer was indeed a false answer since it was used for document clustering and not word clustering, here is the real answer.

What you are looking for is [word2vec](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/).
Indeed, word2vec is a google tool based on deep-learning that works really well. It transforms words into vectorial representation, and therefore allows you to do multiple things with it.

For example, one of its many examples that work well are algebric relation of words:

- vector('puppy') - vector('dog') + vector('cat') is close to vector('kitten')
- vector('king') - vector('man') + vector('woman') is close to vector('queen')

What it means by that is it can sort of encompass the context of a word, and therefore it will work really well for numerous applications.

When you have vectors instead of words, you can pretty much do anything you want. You can for example do a k-means clustering with a cosine distance as the measure of dissimilarity...

Hope this answers well to your question. You can read more about word2vec in different papers or websites if you'd like. I won't link them here since it is not the subject of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Word clustering will be **really disappointing** because the computer does not understand language.

You could use **levenshtein distance** and then do **hierarchical clustering**.

But:

- `dog` and `fog` have a distance of 1, i.e. are highly similar.
- `dog` and `cat` have 3 out of 3 letters different.

So unless you can **define a good measure of similarity**, don't cluster words.

Comment: Word2Vec identifies words of similar meaning without needing to understand the language. Have a look.

Comment: Last time I tried, I found as many examples that did not work, as I found that worked.